# String Buffer thread safety

Tags: java, stringbuffer

StringBuffer is known to be thread-safe in Java which means it provides synchronized access to multiple threads.. But when I run the below code, it does not run same as in synchronization block.. What am I missing here?

```
class Hackerearth{
    static StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("String Buffer Multithreading test");
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Thread1();
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Thread2();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }


    public static void Thread1(){
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            s.setCharAt(i, ((char) ((int) (Math.random() * 26) + 97)));
            System.out.println("Thread is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ".S is: " + s);
            if(i == s.length() - 1){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    s = new StringBuffer("String Buffer Multithreading test");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void Thread2(){
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            s.setCharAt(i, ((char) ((int) (Math.random() * 26) + 97)));
            System.out.println("Thread is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ".S is: " + s);
            if(i == s.length() - 1){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    s = new StringBuffer("String Buffer Multithreading test");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: What's the output and what is the output you expected?

Comment: I expected either of thread 1 or thread 2 whichever runs first to complete its execution like in synchronized block.. But it is not working that way

Comment: The reference `StringBuffer s` is not thread safe, so you can't replace it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Can you please elaborate or provide some doc?

Comment: When you have a synchronized object, it doesn't make references to it thread safe in any useful way.

Comment: It's only individual calls to `StringBuffer` like `append` or `setCharAt` that are synchronized and are guaranteed to maintain invariants about the internal state of the buffer. If you need larger scoped usages of it to be atomic, you still need to do your own synchronization.

Comment: Got it.. It is different from synchronized block.. Thanks